# Using taskkill with php

Tags: php, windows-server-2008, taskkill

I work on a Web-Panel to start and end programs on my Windows Server.

The server is a dedicated server with Windows Web Server 2008 R2 and Plesk Panel.

My php code:

```
taskkill /F /IM Gotcha_Antihack.exe 2>errors.txt
pclose(popen($cmd, "r"));
```

Text from the errors.txt:

> FEHLER: Zugriff verweigert. (Error: access denied)

Can't I execute the taskkill (permissions for the Internet User are granted) or can't the taskkill end the process (the same user start the process)?

Comment: `http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-kill.php#102094` shows a process killing function for Windows.

Comment: @WaleedKhan: Class 'COM' not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was about the Windows User Account Control. I have to give the ISS User the rights for the command.